# Set cookie in one Google (golang) cloud function, redirect to a second Google (golang) cloud function and access the cookie

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, http-redirect, setcookie

Below is sample Go code for two Google cloud functions.
Each function is in a different project.
I want to set a cookie in the first function (myfunction1), redirect to the second function (myfunction2), and access the cookie from that second function.
I've tried a variety of parameters and values for setting the cookie but the second function always hits the error "Error getting mycookie: http: named cookie not present".

**// Sample code for function https://us-central1-*project1*.cloudfunctions.net/*myfunction1***

```
myCookie := http.Cookie{
    userCookie := http.Cookie{
    Name: "mycookie", 
    Value: "foo", 
    Path: "/",
    MaxAge: 60 * 60,
    HttpOnly: true,
    Secure: true,
    SameSite: http.SameSiteLaxMode,
    Domain: ".cloudfunctions.net",
}
http.SetCookie(w, &myCookie)

url := "https://us-central1-project2.cloudfunctions.net/myfunction2"
http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
```

**// sample code for function https://us-central1-*project2*.cloudfunctions.net/*myfunction2***

```
cookie, err := r.Cookie("mycookie")
if err != nil {
 log.Fatalf("Error getting mycookie: %v", err)
} 
log.Println("cookie: ", cookie.Value)
```

Comment: If you put Firebase Hosting in front of your functions you can effectively proxy them to the same host, and you won't have to play games with trying to get them to cross domains.

Comment: This [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) explains how to use and protect cookies. My recommendation is to set up Firebase Hosting and follow Doug's advice. Another option is to use a custom HTTP header to share small amounts of data. Deploying a load balancer and a domain is also possible. No matter what which method you decide on, do not deploy cross-origin cookies for domains you do not control (cloudfunctions.net).

Comment: @DougStevenson - Thanks for the suggestion.  I've done nothing with Firebase so far but I'll take a look.  I'm hoping someone either looks at the sample code and can point out what to change, or state it's impossible to do what I'm wanting to do without a proxy or similar additional architecure.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Thanks for the link.  Good info but I don't see anything that seems to solve my issue. I do control both functions. I'd be happy to use a custom HTTP header but from what I read, HTTP headers are not sent for an HTTP redirect. Can you advise a way to set/send a custom HTTP header for an HTTP redirect?

Comment: Your function sets an HTTP header in the response to the client. The client then adds the header in its request to the other function. I am assuming that you are controlling the client code as well. If you don't then your option is to use a domain name so that you can set a same-origin cookie. That means deploying Firebase Hosting, HTTP Load Balancer, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Thanks. I am controlling the client code too.  I thought the http.Redirect in the first function would cause direct execution of the second function without returning to the client first.  I was trying to do this: client calls myfunction1, myfunction1 redirects to myfunction2, myfunction2 returns HTML page to client.

Comment: You are adding detail via comments that are not in your post. Edit your post will all the required details. I think you are misunderstanding how redirects work. Function A returns an HTTP status code with the new destination (Function B) in a Location header. It is up to the client code to read that response and act in any way it wants.

Comment: @JohnHanley - Thanks.  A fundamental misunderstanding on my part. Back to to the design phase.